# Get image from nodejs backend not works in Angular 403 forbbiden

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript

I want to display images from directory on my server.
I am using nodejs and express
do simple in controller:

```
exports.listImages = (req, res) => {
    //it comes from frontend from which dir should I get image
    let filename = req.params.filename;
    //check if filename is correct ( just for me )
    console.log('filename: '+filename);
   function readFilesSync(dir) {
     const files = [];
     
     fs.readdirSync(dir).forEach((filename) => {
       const name = path.parse(filename).name;
       const ext = path.parse(filename).ext;
       const filepath = path.resolve(dir, filename);
       const stat = fs.statSync(filepath);
       const isFile = stat.isFile();

       if (isFile)
         files.push({
           name,
           ext,
         });
     });
    //sending image name and extension
     return files;
   }
  
  const files = readFilesSync(myDir + filename);
  console.log(files);
  res.send(files);
};
```

And there is my front:

Service:

```
  getImages(filename): Observable<any> {
   return this.http.get(API_URL + `/files/${filename}`);
  }
```

.ts
"Test is directory name just for test"

```
   this.getImagesService.getImages("Test").subscribe(data => {
  this.showImages = data;
  console.log(JSON.stringify(this.showFilesNames))
}, err => {
  console.log(err);
});
```

And my html

```
 <div class="masonry-card">
   <p>{{item.name}}{{item.ext}}</p> <!-- Just to be sure that I got image name and extension Test under is just for test ( this is name of dir ) -->
  <img masonryLazy loading="lazy" src="https://my_domain/api/getimages/files/Test/{{item.name}}{{item.ext}}"/>
</div>
```

And i got every time in my console 403 forbidden.
I got correct image name and extension.
But can't display this image.

What is wrong here?

Want to get mansory gallery

-Edit
added server.js

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const cors = require("cors");
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const helmet = require("helmet");

const app = express();

app.use(cors());
app.use(helmet());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.json({
  limit: '30mb'
}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true,
  limit: '30mb'
}));

const db = require("./app/models");
global.__basedir = __dirname;

app.get("/api", (req, res) => {
  res.json({ message: "Hi." });
});

// routes
require("./app/routes/getimages.routes")(app);

process.env.NODE_ENV = 'production';
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3012;
//const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}.`);
});


app.use((req, res, next) => {

});

app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
  
  console.error(err.message);
  if (!err.statusCode) err.statusCode = 500;
  res.status(err.statusCode).send(err.message);
  next();
});
```

Comment: What server are you running (assuming express), do you have any auth in there? 403 is forbidden, so there's something else in there somewhere.

Comment: Yep express and JWT token everything else also menu based on JWT token and roles.
Only problem with images

Comment: I'm guessing it's the JWT. Can you post your server file?

Comment: You get the images correctly if you put the address directly on a browser?

Comment: what type of server you used to storage images? I think you don't have permission to access this image or this folder

Comment: @GabrielFonseca no got - 403

Comment: @mintquan my local server I got images in directory

Comment: @Phix edited my post

Comment: @MarkeZ, the problem is in the backend - maybe one of those express decorators or something in the implementation of your method. 

That log at the start of the method shows in the console when you run the endpoint?  

`console.log('filename: '+filename);`